Is it bad to branch off data traces into two separate connectors?
I have a project where some connectors (Ethernet and USB) may need to point in different directions depending on the application (either parallel to, or perpendicular to, the PCB), but it is not possible to merely rotate the whole PCB because of space constraints.
I was thinking of solving this by exposing the traces going to the connectors to a pin header just in front of them, and then making a separate add-on board which plugs into those traces and forwards them to a set of differently-oriented connectors.
However, I am not comfortable enough with PCB design to know whether this is a terrible idea or not. Will this "branching" ruin things in terms of noise, EMC etc? And if not, where should I put filters, magnetics etc? Right next to each connector, or on the main board after the branches have merged so that I only need one set of protection?
Of course, only one set of connectors will be used at a time, meaning that there should be no current going through the branch that is not in use, so I would think the unused branches shouldn't act as antennas or anything, right?
Specifically, the Ethernet is 100Mbps and the USB is High-Speed (480 Mbps). I should be able to keep both branches below like 5 cm total length.
Here is an illustration to show what I mean:


Select a connector that is available in two variants at 90degrees.  Populate the relevant connector and use the same IO board to plug in.

Another option is an active two-port analogue switch chip (which are available in versions designed for specific protocol signalling, eg USB, PCIe). The switch is controlled by a pin on the plug-in connector.  Pulled high by default, it goes straight on.  Grounded it goes to the connector.

I wouldn't rely on it working well. If the accessory board is plugged in, the traces and connectors on the baseboard will act as large stubs on the signal transmission lines which may cause signal integrity issues (particularly for the USB at high speed).
You could prototype to try it out, but you might find yourself in a situation where some boards work and others don't.

You could keep the idea of using a header for a separate connection, but instead of feeding the baseboard connections straight to the SoM, feed them too out onto the connector. Then use a loopback board plugged in to the header when not using the accessory card.
This way when the accessory card is used, the baseboard connectors are completely isolated from the SoM (no stubs). When the accessory card is not used, the loopback board plugged into the header will connect up the baseboard connectors without stubs.

Alternatively, instead of having the Eth/USB connectors on the baseboard, you could just feed them to your expansion header. Then have two variants of the accessory board, one which plugs in vertically, and one which plugs in horizontally. Use whichever accessory board matches your required connector orientation.

I'd go along with your final idea as being least likely to be problematic.

This might be an application for flat flex or rigid-flex construction:

From: Rigid-Flex PCB - PCB Prototype the Easy Way | PCBWay
You get the BOM reduction of not needing headers and multiple connectors, and the flexibility to put the connector sub-board anywhere you like, within reason.
The fab process is more expensive, and particularly if you don't need many connections (as seems the case here), you might consider just a basic off-the-shelf flex cable / jumper, and suitable connectors.
Wiring such a cable, or layout of the flex section, does require some attention.  Ethernet can be wired as side-by-side pairs, easily enough,
USB should be wired as signals over ground plane where possible.  That may not be possible here, and the next best case is G-(S+)-G-(S-)-G, alternating ground and signal lines.  I would reserve additional grounds outside to all wire in parallel, to give the best chance of success, as without a ground plane proper, this construction will have heightened sensitivity to EMI, and chance for emissions.  (Note that, with bypass caps, VCC can also serve as GND for RF purposes.)  The impedance will in any case be higher than nominal, and a minimum-length jumper is advised (<5cm?) to minimize issues with mismatch.
Note that, for two-layer flex, the opposite problem arises: impedance can be rather easily made ponderously low, as the substrate (dielectric) height is very low.  This is often addressed by using a crosshatch ground plane; a pattern of 1-2mm pitch will have little effect on signal quality at USB edge rates (it would be sensible with ~50ps edges or below), but does have the downside of poorer shielding value compared to a solid pour (but better than single ground traces adjacent in a single-layer cable).  (The crosshatch is probably also less prone to fatigue, though I gather repeating flexing is not a requirement in this case.)
Altogether, that would be around 15 pins.  I would suggest leaving open-circuit gaps between Ethernet pairs, leading to a pinout such as:
1. TD+
2. TD-
3. NC
4. RD+
5. RD-
6. NC
7. VCC
8. VCC
9. GND
10. USB+
11. GND
12. USB-
13. GND
14. GND
15. GND

Or, probably a few more vacancies between Ethernet pairs and anything else should be reserved, to allow for higher isolation voltage (this is direct from the connector, media interface, right?).  Ethernet is rated 1.5kV isolation, so it's worth skipping a few pins even in a 2mm+ pitch header.
If Ethernet is PHY side instead, then you need to pass ground (RF ground, and probably VCCA too) as well as the pairs, and the jumper should further be kept short to minimize stub length of these pairs (which the USB priority already covers; it's just that this way, both require it, not just one).  On the upside, isolation is not required, and likely the grounds can be made common so you can just utterly spam the cable full of ground wires -- again, still not a ground plane, but more grounds the merrier and we can do our best to substitute.  Without isolation concerns, a fine pitch cable can be used.

The impedance match will be an issue with your pinout. If the SS construction is good for Ethernet 100 ohms differential, GSGSG for USB would be far from 90 ohm differential.

"Issue" is relative. I have covered all the important points here; limiting length to a few cm is sufficient for USB data rates.

480 Mbps USB has 500ps risetime, or about 3 inches on PCB. 2cm is already a quarter of risetime. Conservative approach would be to say less than 1cm is OK, and a few cm would be very poor already. Like you said, it is relative issue, and those are the numbers relative to USB 480Mbps data rate.

In a word, yes, it is a bad idea, and because you stated that unused branches shouldn't have much effect, shows that you seem to have very little experience about high speed buses and transmission lines, because brances do have an effect, whether or not they are used or not.
Branches are always detrimetal for high-speed data transmission lines such as USB and Ethernet.
The 480 Mbps USB requires 500ps signal rise/fall times, which equal to 700 MHz bandwidth requirement. A signal edge on PCB travels about 7.5cm in 500ps. As the PCB track must be 25% or preferably 10% of this length to not be considered as transmission line, it must be less than 2cm, preferably less than 1cm to not cause any problems. Which includes the wiring inside the connector, so in reality, the PCB wiring must effectively be zero length.
They do not necessarily act as antennas, but it will be a split point for energy going on the transmission line, for USB it means a single 90 ohm transmission line is split to two 90 ohm transmission lines and that's already an impedance mismatch point, as the load of two transmission lines is 45 ohms, leading to reflections and lower signal amplitude going to one branch. Then the signal will fully reflect back from the open end of the unused branch.
And branches generally should not exist anyway on these lines, as the connections are supposed to be point-to-point, with wiring properly sized for correct transmission line properties for correct characteristic impedance.
Any generic high-speed routing guide will instruct to avoid branches and stubs at all cost.
Even having a pin header may be a bad idea, depending on how you will design and wire it for high speed transmission lines.
If those are RJ45 magjacks, i.e. connectors with integrated magnetics, you can't have two of them in parallel. If you really must have things in parallel, they should be passive connectors, and one set of discrete magnetics.
What might be a solution, is to have a pinheader, and two different boards for connectors, and you only choose one connector board. Or at least use components like 0 ohm resistors to route the connections to either onboard connectors or pinheader. It will avoid the branching but may still be a poor solution.

75cm in 500ps is impossible.  10ish cm is more likely (approx 2/3 c)

@OskarSkog Fixed. Thanks.

I do stuff like this a lot prototyping.
If you put series 0 ohm resistors after the closest connector, in the case you're using said connector, just depopulate the 0 ohm resistors. This 'opens' the stub to the unused connector.
If you're using the furthest away connector, populate the 0 ohm resistors and the closest unused connector is just a passthrough. Don't populate both simultaneously.
Similarly, you could do 2 sets of 0 ohm resistors that you populate based on connector used.
If it works out with signal integrity, these resistors could be jumpers instead.

All that matters is if the parasitics of the extra taps on the comms lines are going to affect your impedance enough to affect the data signal integrity.
One important detail to define is: are there going to be multiple ports plugged in at the same time?  If no, the impedance effect of the parasitics of the extra taps are likely negligible and this should be fine.  If yes, then it really depends what gets connected to those extra taps.

You don't use any numbers to back things up. I'd say a 5cm stub causes problems, because 480Mbps USB requires 500ps risetime, and quarter length critical limit is already about 2cm, so stubs would have to be less than 1cm to have likely no effect. Including the contacts in the connector. Which leaves almost no room for PCB wiring for the tap.

There's nothing to back up, I'm not claiming anything specific other than the general behavior and dependence on impedance.  Of course it depends on speed.

@SPieiga but speed is defined by the question to be high speed USB, which always has the same requirements.
